# jQuery filtering dynamic html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a HTML template using the `$.get` function and I would like to parse this HTML and inject my own values into it.  So far I have tried the below snippet, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/locations', function(newRow) {
    var existing_elem = $('.edit-table tr:last'); 
    existing_elem.after(newRow);
    var appendedRow = existing_elem;
    appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Name"] > span').text(v.location_name);
    appendedRow.find('input').val(v.location_name);
    appendedRow.effect("highlight", {color: '#CCB4A5'}, 1000);
});
```

The value of newRow when loaded is:

```
<tr>
  <td data-th="Name"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
  <input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="location_name" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the value of `v.location_name` and how do you then attach the HTML to the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to append the loaded content into the DOM. Then, select and edit any element you want:

**EDIT (#2)**

HTML (Assumung this is the html loaded: 2 columns)

```
<tr>
  <td data-th="Name"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
  <input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="location_name" value="">    </td>
  <td data-th="LastName"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
  <input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="location_name" value="">    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/locations', function(newRow) {
   var existing_elem = $('#existing_elem'); 
   //Append the html      
   existing_elem.append(newRow);
   //Select the appended html
   var appendedRow = existing_elem.children('tr');
   //Select eny elem inside the appended html
   appendedRow.addClass('appended');
   appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Name"] > span').text('your_text');
   appendedRow.find('input').val('new_value');
   //Second column
   appendedRow.find('td').eq(1).find('input').val('another_value');
});
```

Comment: This seems to work but how would I change it if I wanted to change multiple elements in the HTML string?

Comment: For example if my table had multiple columns and I wanted to change another span, how would I chain that together?

Comment: please see my edit above.  I have changed the code to reflect your suggestions.  However I have had to change the selector slightly and now it is not working.

Comment: Select the last row as the appendedRow: -->  var appendedRow = $('table tr:last-of-type');

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$(newRow).find('.edit-input-text').text(v.location_name);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xptthgrm/)

```
//Create a jQuery object from your ajax response
var newRow = $('<tr><td data-th="Name"><span class="edit-input-text"></span><input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="location_name" value=""></td></tr>');

//Manipulate
newRow.find('.edit-input-text').text("I am new here")

//Do whatever
$('#demo').append(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector has issue. Try this -

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/locations', function(newRow) {
    $(newRow).filter('tr td[data-th="Name"] span').text(v.location_name);
});
```

where the selector `'tr td[data-th="Name"] span'` should be noticed
OR

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/locations', function(newRow) {
    $('[data-th="Name"]', newRow).find('span').text(v.location_name);
});
```